# Why the interference voltage of cooling fan is different in component test and vehicle?

Tags: circuit-analysis, brushless-dc-motor, emc, harmonics

I have tested a DC cooling fan used in vehicle. The fan is like this [vehicle cooling fan](https://m.indiamart.com/proddetail/car-radiator-fans-19761314512.html).

In the component test, the cooling fan is connected with 12 V battery and two LISNs. The oscilloscope measured the voltage and current of the fan. Due to the rotation of the fan, there are some low frequency harmonics in FFT results of the voltage and current data. The DC voltage (0Hz) amplitudethe is 12V, and the amplitude at 920 Hz is about 0.02 V, which is the max amplitude of the harmonics frequency.

When I link the fan to a vehicle circuit, the amplitude is about 0.0004 V at about 1000 Hz, which is the max amplitude of the harmonics frequency.

Why is there such a difference between the component test and vehicle test?

Comment: What are the characteristics of the battery?  The vehicle circuit?  Frankly, I'm surprised you're only seeing 20mV amplitude on the battery.

Comment: How exactly do you measure this that gives a resolution down to 0.0004 V? Was that measured in an EMC lab or what? Otherwise I wouldn't expect an oscilloscope to give accurate readings of such low voltages.

Answer (score 0):

Car batteries vary in voltage. Typical '12V' lead-acid voltage is more like 12.7V when charged. This would presumably correlate to a slightly higher RPM compared to your 12V bench supply, which would explain the FFT harmonic being shifted up compared to your bench test.

Also, the ripple voltage is miniscule (20mV for yor bench, 0.4mV for your vehicle.) Frankly speaking, for a high-power device like that fan that's amazingly low. The difference could be explained away by probe coupling, ground impedance, probe placement, inductance in the fan wiring, or the impedance of your power supply compared to a battery.

A more meaningful measurement would be to use a current probe. Then you'd see more clearly what harmonics the fan is imposing onto the power supply.